# Add scrollbars to background image in panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to put scrollbars on my panel (WinForms) to view the all background image.
Because the background image of that panel is too big i cant see the all image.

I also want that the background image will be present in her original size -- thats why she so big and I what to use scrollbars.

I can't use pictureBox because I need to draw on this background image, that's why I'm using panel.

Comment: You can draw on the `PictureBox`. Yet, here is [scrollable form](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/ScrollableForm.htm) (`AutoScroll = true` makes basically any control scrollable).

Answer (score 1):

you are asking an strange question so i give you an strange answer:

1. put a transparent panel into your original panel (which that has background).
2. set size of this transparent panel similar to your background image size.
3. enable your original panels AutoScroll.